# Bootstrap 4 table, how to reduce width of <td>? last minimum it goes to 25px(padding removed), I want to make it 8px width using bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, html-table, less, width, default

I want to keep the first column empty to add background-color and width to be 8px width.
Below is the code:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="bg-danger" width="8px"></td>
            <td>red</td>
            <td>orange</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[I am trying to get final output as following image url.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKJhg.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to width property in an inline style tag not directly like this...

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="bg-danger" width="800px"></td>
            <td>red</td>
            <td>orange</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    
  </body>
</html>
```